# Filter php function return value

Tags: php, function

Lets say we have function:

```
function foo() {
    return "bar";
}
```

Is it possible to add some filter to `foo()` function, for example to make it returning double value like `"barbar"` without changing the function itself.

So we would have:

```
foo(); //returns "bar"
function filter($&val) {
    $val = $val . $val;
}
add_filter_to_function('foo','filter');
foo(); //returns "barbar"
```

And then anywhere foo() is used, it would return filtered value without changing code that calls `foo()` to something like `foo() . foo()` and without changing the function itself

Comment: Even if that was possible, what do you think would be the implications on code maintainability? What problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps there is a simpler way.

Comment: It seems you have a glitch in your architecture since in normal situation you'll never need to change function's code on the fly

Comment: I've got a lot of functions in some class and each of them have return in serveral places. I dont want to refactor code, but to add filter for each of this function and istead of inputing it to each of return part of code.

Comment: extend the classes then, and override the functions...

Comment: Huuh that wouldnt be less complicated imo.

Comment: @Kluska000 but if you'll change the function itself - you'll not be able to predict what will happend in other parts of your application (which probably rely on it)

Comment: less complicated? what you yourself want to do is not even possible...  extending classes is exactly what you do in OOP to manipulate the output of certain functions.

Comment: I think you should provide us a not-too-simplified problem. Are functions or class methods? How many different functions are there? How many call? How many class? :)

Comment: I'm making some WYSIWYG editor that is working on live website. I need to add some tags to given group of generated by php functions elements only when its turned on by user. Im sure it would not break application if their outputs would be appended and preppended with some values I need to add to them. But as app is big, have a lot of pagges I dont know where functions are called. Adding proper conditions and modifing returning in each of functions would need a lot of refactoring.

Comment: Why not add a particular parameter to your function , and change return value depending of this value ? POO override is also a better solution

Comment: Its ok FaceOfJock, but I'm lazy and if I've got 100 functions, where some of them have more than 1 return I just thought that this kind of filter would be 5-liner code that would make it all - foreach class methods and add filters to them.

Comment: Same as if you want to create and call a function which changes their return value. You would spend the same effort, but you will create some awful code design

Comment: It's easier to put filter on rivers way than to modify mountains chemical composition it puts into water. Thats my idea. I know that it may be bad, you would not really know what happens inside the mountain etc...

Comment: @Kluska000 I'm sorry, but that's a bad analogy. Also, what you want to accomplish will probably lead to very poor code design, and those same results can be obtained in a better way by using some of the posted answers.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, there is a [RunKit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension ([runkit_function_redefine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php) in particular for your question) which allow you to manipulate with code's objects (such as function or classes) on the fly.

But I think you're doing something wrong if you need to change your function's code on that way - so may be you should reconsider your goal and resolve your original problem with another tools.

If you need to call your function with some parameters in some special cases, you can use something like:

```
function foo($x, $y)
{
   //do stuff
}

function bar($x, $y, $z)
{
   //do stuff with $z?
   foo($x, $y);
}
```

and use `bar()` instead of `foo()` then - in certain places (which you need to adjust)

Comment: Its just about fact I need to slighlty change ouptut of big group of functions anywhere they are used depending on some parameter. I think it would be useful to do so instead of modifing a lot of places when functions returns something. Also a lot of framworks has build in filter systems like wordpress etc. And as I dont know exacly where those function are used and I would need to add proper condition in each new place I thought it would be great.

Comment: Then you should just override your functions - that's all. Create a function that calls existing function, for example.

Comment: Is it possible to override function itself then?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply concatenate the value on itself:

```
$val = foo();
$val .= $val;
```

or if your function really needs to have a double value returned, then you should probably look at refactoring your `foo()` function, because it doesn't seem to do what you want.
Either that, or accept one of the other answers that tells you to wrap `foo()` around another function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot internally change the return value of a function, if it's static.

If you had `foo($var)`, you could change the state of $var, and everytime you call foo($var) lately, you would recieve the new value, but in your case it's almost not possible.

You have to call the other function everytime you need double value:

```
function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}
function filter($func) {
    return $func.$func;
}
echo filter(foo());
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn your function into an object method and then the add_filter_to_function would add the filter to the object.

Then when you called the function it would be able to use the filters that have been assigned to the object the function belongs to.